# Template randomly not found using DDEV

Tags: error-templates

I am using DDEV and the following files tree structure:

[image]

Where "_index.twig" is the single section type and where "_item.twig" is the channel section type.

For all of them I want to extend from "base-template.twig" which is located at the root of the "templates" folder.

This is how I'm extending:

```
{% extends "base-template" %}
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it shows the following error:

[image]

This is the section settings for the services entry type:

[image]

I don't know if DDEV uses some type of cache, I didn't enable anything.

This is my DDEV config:

```
name: alanda
type: craftcms
docroot: web
php_version: "8.0"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
  type: mariadb
  version: "10.4"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
```

**UPDATE** I didn't change anything, and it's working again:

[image]

But it only works sometimes. If I refresh the page deleting the cache, sometimes, it shows the error again.

Comment: I'm facing the same project right now and a few times before. It's inconsistent but very annoying when it happens.. when cd'ing to dir via `DDEV SSH` and doing `ls` the file is definitely there. But seems rather to be related to DDEV not Craft CMS